# AdMob works when I use test ID's but doesn't show ads when i use real ones

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I've looked everywhere and tried waiting, its been 3 days but still nothing, I also tried updating my payment details but it says i can only do that when I reach the threshold.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your app is published on playstore?

Comment: Actually Admob doesn't show real Ads before Publishing App in Playstore. If Test Ads are Working it means your integration is correct and no need to worry. Real ads are visible when your app is published.

Comment: Oh damn, It's not published, I thought I could see ads before I publish it, thank you guys